# Transforming an integral

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

Say I have a 2d function $f(x,y)$ and I choose to do this integral:
$$\int_{A} \left| \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}\right| dtdn$$
where $n$ is the coordinate along the contour curves and $t$ is the coordinate along the curves normal to the contour curves, on which the gradient vector is tangent.

How do I transform that into an integral in $x$ and $y$:
$$\int_{A} ? dxdy$$

Answer (score 1):

I would say it is
$$
\int_{A'} \left|\nabla f(x,y)\right| dx dy
$$
because your choice of coordinates imply $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} = \nabla f$, and also the jacobian determinant of the change of variable must be $1$ because the contour lines are orthogonal to the gradient lines. I suppose $t$ and $n$ are arclength coordinates along these curves.

Of course, the description of the domain $A$ in terms of $t, n$ will be different from its description in terms of $x, y$.